# finding which extra columns are present in table1 in comparison with table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to find out which extra columns are present in `table1` as compared to `table2`. So, I thought of using information from `sys.columns` as follows.

However, I don't think I get the correct result here, because my table1 contains `90` columns, and table2 contains `50`, so I was expecting my result to have only `40` rows. However, it has more.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  object_id = Object_id('CardioVascular.AcuteCareHeartFailureInpatientCoded')
EXCEPT
(SELECT NAME
 FROM   sys.columns
 WHERE  object_id = Object_id('CardioVascular.HeartFailureInpatientCoded'))
```

I also saw the `minus` keyword in a website, and thought of using it, but get some errors.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  object_id = Object_id('CardioVascular.AcuteCareHeartFailureInpatientCoded')
minus
SELECT NAME
FROM   sys.columns
WHERE  object_id = Object_id('CardioVascular.HeartFailureInpatientCoded')
```

Comment: The arithmetic 90 - 50 = 40 doesn't necessary apply.  No more than 50 columns can be the same between the two tables, but the number that are the same could be anywhere from 0 to 50.  So, the number that don't match could be anywhere from 40 to 90.

Comment: In SQL Server, use `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to be very useful in these situations.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'AcuteCareHeartFailureInpatientCoded') t1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'HeartFailureInpatientCoded') t2 ON t1.COLUMN_NAME = t2.COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, 
       COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table1' AND 
      COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table2')
```

just replace 'table1' and 'table 2' with your table name